# Filemaker Pro 18 Delete all Records from All tables

Tags: filemaker

I have a fm file with around 70 tables populated with test data, I want to delete all the records so I can use it to import real data, wondering if there's a way to delete all records. There is a delete script but it can only do table by table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply save a copy of the file as clone (no records)?